# Unknown reason why cannot get ssh access via public keys anymore

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Server 1 -> Centos 7.
Server 2 -> AlmaLinux 9.
By mistake I
`rsync -e “ssh…” /dir1/ user2@domain2:/home/user2/dir2/`
instead of
`rsync -e “ssh…” /dir1 user2@domain2:/home/user2/dir2/`
The final result at the target has to be `/home/user2/dir2/dir1`

dir1 contains only 5 directories.
So I carefully deleted them in dir2 checking if there was files that must not be deleted (existing ones before `rsync`).
Then I tried the correct `rsync` from server1 but i couldn't.  I got

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Server2 (the target) only allows ssh connections with public key. I connected several times from server1 to server2 "automatically" using my keys.
`/home/user2/.ssh` exists and wasn't altered.  It has the file `authorization_keys` 0600 and it contains a few public keys including user1's.
If I allow ssh login with password in server2 I log in succesfully.

user1 logs in other server2 accounts using public key. The issue is with user2.

I've read some similar threads looking for the output error but all write about  generating keys, file and directory permissions.

.ssh is 0700 and authorized_keys is 0600. Iam telling the story how the things happened.

The client has the same permissions. Both are remote. I also get the same error from my laptop while I was able to get access before deleting those dirs at the server. Both remote server a client user is root.

The client root dir is 0555 while server is 0775

My laptop user/.ssh is 0700 and user is 0755.

server1, my Mac laptop and my Ubuntu desktop are the only clients whose public keys are stored at server1’s authorized_keys and I am the only who has access to all of them.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments, [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1774543/edit) the question instead to keep it up to date and everything relevant available. I deleted my comments, I'd suggest you do the same, as I've added your comments now verbatim. This leaves room for others to comment. I think the root cause is that target server's `.ssh` directory and files therein either have incorrect permissions or ownership; or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The client root dir is 0555 while server is 0775
```

**I changed server root permission to 0555**, same as client and it was fixed.
I don't realize why deleting a few /root/ sub-directories changed /root permission.
Deleting was performing rm -rf /root/subdirs from my ssh laptop connection.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).